# Deleting a custom audience from an ad account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook's documentation doesn't seem to cover it (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/custom-audience-targeting/).

Running:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{audience_id}?method=DELETE&{access_token}
```

returns the following json:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported delete request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

How can I do it, if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request did work for a different `access_token`. I must have had problems with the `access_token` permissions.